# iBeacon App State - Best practice?

Tags: ibeacon

What is the preferred state of the app in order to receive a proximity-based offer - App in foreground, background or not-yet-launched?

There are mixed opinions on this, some say how should a user know he should have the app launched, on the other hand if the app is not launched, a deamon process needs to be listening to BLE packets (and consuming battery).

I'm trying to understand what some of the *real* applications are doing in practice.

Answer (score 1):

Beacon apps that present offers when a user is nearby **typically require background detection of beacons**, because it is unlikely the user will know to manually open the app at the right time.

This is possible on both iOS and Android, provided that the beacon app is already installed on the phone.   Both platforms allow ways to do **low power beacon scanning in the background** that will deliver a callback to an app when a beacon matching an identifier pattern is detected.

The basic practice is to have the app register for these callbacks the first time it runs, so even if the phone is rebooted, it will be notified of a detection.

As you say, background scanning requires some battery usage, but there are **optimizations that make this acceptable** on both Android and iOS.  These optimizations are automatic on iOS and the implementation closed source and undocumented.  On Android, similar optimizations are provided by the open source Android Beacon Library.  You can read about how background launching works [here](http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/background_launching.html) and battery saving [here](http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/battery_manager.html).

Full disclosure: I am lead developer on the Android Beacon Library project.